# NetLogo BehaviorSpace- Exporting Histogram with each run

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

When you right click a histogram in NetLogo, it has an "Export" option and it makes a csv file that contains a column of x values and total y values (like the data from a normal distribution for example). I would like to use BehaviorSpace to export that data with each run (appended to one csv file), but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: check the NetLogo export primitives: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#export-cmds, in particular `export-plot`